# Passing Object from Vue.js Page to Aspx Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vue.js, axios

I have a Vue page which I'm using Axios for to send a POST request (with a View Model object) to a certain aspx page of mine. The issue is that I need to be able to grab it right on that page, I would assume through the `Request` object; I *don't* want to grab it through an API.

My code is as follows:

--Vue Code

```
pagePost({payload}){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const payloadObject = Object.assign({}, payload);

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/MyTestPage.aspx',
            crossdomain: true,
            data: payloadObject,
            responseType: {},
        })
        .then(function (response){
            return response;
        })
    })
},
```

-- On my .aspx page, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
var firstName = Request["payLoadObject.FirstName"];
var lastName = Request["payLoadObject.LastName"];
```

How would I go about accomplishing this? I have tried to send it a few different ways, and grab on the page a few different ways with no luck.

****NOTE: I removed a lot of things out of my code for privacy reasons, so the syntax might not be correct anymore.**

Comment: FYI, your JS is wrong. Remove the `new Promise` and `return axios({...})`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I removed a lot of things out of my code for privacy reasons, so the syntax might not be correct anymore :)

Comment: That doesn't matter. Your use of the `new Promise` is wrong.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ah, gotcha, Thank you for pointing it out, I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. Please add the C# method that handles the request.

Comment: @AluanHaddad There is no method, this is your typical aspx page that I'm posting to where you can call C# code from within the page.